# Docker, changing service name from PHP to different returns 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: php, docker, apache, docker-compose

I have docker-compose.yml which looks like this.

```
version: "3.6"
services:
  php:
   build: './php/'
   ports:
     - 9000:9000
   networks:
     - backend
   volumes: 
     - .\puppet_projects\pname\pname:/var/www/html/pname
  apache_pname:
    build: './apache/'
    depends_on:
      - php
    ports: 
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
    volumes: 
      - .\puppet_projects\pname\pname:/var/www/html/pname
networks:
  frontend:
  backend:
```

And when I am starting docker-compose up project works properly but after changing **php** to ie. **php_pname** I am receiving 503 Site Unavailable

```
version: "3.6"
services:
  php_pname:
   build: './php/'
   ports:
     - 9000:9000
   networks:
     - backend
   volumes: 
     - .\puppet_projects\pname\pname:/var/www/html/pname
  apache_pname:
    build: './apache/'
    depends_on:
      - php_pname
    ports: 
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
    volumes: 
      - .\puppet_projects\pname\pname:/var/www/html/pname
networks:
  frontend:
  backend:
```

What couses error. How can I fix it? Do I have to set up service name to **php** without changing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you use Apache2 as a proxy and it's configured to pass requests to `php` service. When you change the service name, it's internal DNS record in Docker changes as well and so Apache is unable to find `php` anymore.

You can either reflect the change in Apache configuration or add an alias to the `php` service to give it a second name:

```yaml
services:
  php_pname:
   build: './php/'
   ports:
     - 9000:9000
   networks:
     backend:
       aliases:
         - php
```

This way you can access service `php_pname` from `backend` network with both `php_pname` and `php`.